# Error when fetching subject from email using HaskellNet's IMAP

Tags: haskell, imap

I was trying to download the subject of some emails, but I got the following error message:

```
000004:2:1: expecting either "* " or "000004"
```

The following code should reproduce the problem (when username and password is properly replaced):

```
main = do
        conn <- connectIMAPSSL "imap.gmail.com"
        login conn "username" "password"
        boxes <- list conn
        let box = "INBOX"
        select conn box
        uids <- search conn [UNFLAG Seen]
        forM uids $ \uid -> do
            putStrLn "Fetching"
            fetchByString conn uid "BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]"
            putStrLn "Fetched"
```

The main problem is that I'm unsure if it is a problem with my code, HaskellNet or GMail.

Comment: Show us the log of the IMAP connection, please.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to get the log of the IMAP connection.

Comment: Change your password to "guesswork" (nine letters, no quotes) and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a parser error inside HaskellNet.  I have submitted a pull request which you can see [here](https://github.com/jtdaugherty/HaskellNet/pull/22), and in my experience jtdaugherty is pretty quick to respond to these things, so hopefully it'll make its way into mainline HaskellNet soon.

As Jan Kundrát suggested the log of the IMAP connection was invaluable in figuring out the problem.  In terms of raw HaskellNet, the answer to "how do you get the log?" is "define your own BSStream", however since you're using HaskellNet-SSL to get access to gmail the BSStream is already defined for you.

I've added a parameter to HaskellNet-SSL called "sslLogToConsole" which will spit out the IMAP session log inline to STDOUT, prefixed with "HaskellNet-SSL" markers to help you separate them out.  This feature is available in version 0.2.5, so if you have any more problems, hopefully this will help with debugging them!

Edit: jtdaugherty is so fast, in fact, that he'd already merged the changes in before I managed to type this response!

Answer (score 0):

Some clues...I can reproduce the error.

Replacing SUBJECT with UID in the following line does not produce an error.

```
fetchByString conn uid "BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]"
```

This works..

```
fetch conn uid
```

Looking at the source it looks like it should mean the same as this...

```
fetchByString conn uid "BODY[] "
```

but it produces the same error as above. I suspect the problem is not gmail.